# ODBC Data Source SQL Server Connection - Login Failed For User

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, odbc, logins

I have moved my database from an SQL 2005 to a server with SQL 2008.

I am now trying to create an ODBC Data Source.

I am using "With SQL Server authentication using a login ID and password entered by the user" and have entered my Login and password.  The Login is visible in SQL Server Management Studio under Security-> Logins.

The login also contains the exact properties of the same login in my old server.  When I hit next after entering the username and password I get:

```
Connection failed:
SQLState: '28000'
SQL Server Error: 18456
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myUser'.
```

After reading this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332 I realized that the server properties were set to "Windows Authentication Mode" only, but even after changing to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode" I am still having problems connecting.  I can connect with my Windows account though.

Comment: Just a note.  When you change the Server Authentication from Windows Authentication to Mixed Mode.  You'll need to manually enable the SA login if you want it available.  

Personally I would keep it disabled in your case since you have access through your Windows acount.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My answer... From my comments:

The issue was that the server was set to "Windows Authentication Mode" only.
To fix this, launch Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and connect to the database. Then:

1. Right click the server - > Properties
2. Click "Security" in the left side of the "Server Properties" dialog
3. Change server Authentication to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"
4. Click "OK"
5. Restart Associated services. At first I forgot to restart the services, so I was still getting the error, but now I am able to connect without an issue. This was very helpful: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332